# Detect if the selected value in <select> is selected again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know if the selected option is clicked again. for example the foo is selected then i click the select tag again and click foo again.

```
<select name="items" id="item_options">
    <option value="foo">foo</option>         
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
    <option value="boom">boom</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So you want to know when the already selected option is clicked? As compared to knowing if the user changes to a different option and then changes back to the original?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes i want to know if the user clicked the selected option again.

Comment: @alks21jy if something like this isn't trivial to do then there must be good reason for it. I suggest you update your question to explain *why* you are trying to do it as there might be a better alternative.